# unable to compile a simple publisher node

Tags: ros, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i tried to compile a simple node of publish, it give me following error

```
chhonkar@CHHONKAR:~/Desktop/beginner_tutorials/src$ g++ hellop.cpp -o hellop -I/opt/ros/indigo/include -L/opt/ros/indigo/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/indigo/lib -lroscpp -lrosconsole -lrostime
```

error :

```
 /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccBLS7zj.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN3ros13serialization18throwStreamOverrunEv'
 /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp_serialization.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

my code written in cpp is as follow
:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include "sstream"
using namespace ros;
int main (int argc, char**argv)
{
  init (argc,argv,  "hellop");
  NodeHandle n;
  start();
  Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::String>("chatter",1000);    
  Rate loop_rate(10);
int count = 0;
while (ros::ok())
{
    std_msgs::String msg;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss<<"hello oye londe"<<count;
    msg.data = ss.str();
    ROS_INFO("%s", msg.data.c_str());
    chatter_pub.publish(msg);
    spinOnce();
    loop_rate.sleep();
    ++count;
}
return 0;
```

}

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193271/unable-to-compile-a-simple-publisher-node/) by [ASHISH CHHONKAR](https://answers.ros.org/users/20131/ashish-chhonkar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-09-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-09-23**:
you should really be using cmake to compile your nodes, as described in the tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Link libroscpp_serialization.so in your build command but not sure of compilation if any other libraries are missing.

Correct way would be to create a ROS package [CreatingPackage](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage)  make things easy and add your source and update [CMakeLists.txt](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt) and then build with `catkin_make`.

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2